# Disabling transparent persistence on Hibernate 3

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, seam

We are using Seam JBoss Seam 2.2.2 Final Release, and in it contains Hibernate 3.3.1.GA. We have put triggers on update on a table such that, when an update happens on a table, the old record is recorded in a history table.

We have a page that contains fields that populates an entity. When a field is done, an AJAX call is called to a method (in JSF) that updates the entity as needed. The problem is that, Hibernate sees the entity as changed, and updates the DB table accordingly. This increases the history table. We are solely using JPA implementation using Hibernate.

My question is: How do I disable automatic update (known as transparent persistence) in Hibernate? We want to **explicitly** save entities by calling the `EntityManager.persist()` or `EntityManager.merge()` (in the code).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**to answer your question:**

do not update the entity in the method or clear the entitymanager before leaving the method.

**the answer i think you need:**

dont send each individual change to the database but aggregate all changes and only update the persistent entity after the user committed his changes (e.g. a button "save" or "next" or something like that).

Comment: You misunderstood me correctly. Hibernate automatically update changed entity, we don't do an `EntityManager.persist()` or `EntityManager.merge()`. That's what we want to disable, i.e., we want to **explicitly** `persist()` or `merge()` changed entities.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a conversation around your page and use `flush-mode="MANUAL"`. This effectively disables flush until you explicitly perform it (inside your `persist()` method, for example).

The downside of this is that Hibernate must be your persistence provider, because manual flush is not a standard JPA 1.0 feature. Therefore Seams knows how to use it only in Hibernate. This is true at least for Seam versions up to and including 2.2.x. You now use Hibernate so this should not be a problem.

Alternatives:

1. Use a DTO object on the page instead of the real entity object. Clone the entity into the DTO and update the entity before persisting.
2. Use `EntityManager.clear()` to detach all objects from session.